# Change Javascript Var on element onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, onchange, var

All,

I'm trying to change a Javascript var which I use to populate data on chart based on clicking an element, can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone help?

I have the variable below, I want to use the array  below on my chart whenever I click an html element.

```
var monthActualLWDC = [12,54,65,74,23,47,75,23,57,65,45,33]
```

Element,

```
<a id="btn2" onclick="changeTheVariable()" value="monthActualLWDC" class="ui labeled button"></a>
```

Function,

```
  function changeTheVariable() {
     var chartdata = document.getElementById("btn2").value;
  }
```

So when plug `"chartdata"` into the chart, it should display the `"monthActualLWDC"`

```
 new Chart(document.getElementById("mixed-chart"), {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
              labels: ["Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "YTD", "P.FY"],
              datasets: [{
                  label: "Month Actual",
                  type: "line",
                  borderColor: "#002db3",
                  data: chartdata,
                  fill: false
                }, {
                  label: "Prev. Y. Month Actual",
                  type: "line",
                  borderColor: "#000d33",
                  data: monthActualPYLWD,
                  fill: false
                }, {
                  label: "Goal",
                  type: "line",
                  borderColor: "#e60000",
                  data: goalLWD,
                  fill: false
                }, {
                  label: "YTD & P.Fiscal Year",
                  type: "bar",
                  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                  data: ytdpfyLWD,
                },
              ]
            },
            options: {
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'CDC - Champaign Distribution Center - KPI'
              },
              legend: { display: true }
            }
        });
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...need help.

Comment: I don't see any chart there...?

Comment: I added the chart. I'm trying to change the chartdata array based onclick, so the chart updates dynamically based on the <a></a> that get clicked.

Comment: Also, I don't think "value" is valid for an anchor element.

Comment: I tried using button, it also did not work, should I use it on a div?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the input is just a string, it doesn't automatically get evaluated as the variable. If you want to access data using a string name, you should put it in an object whose property names are the strings.

```
var myData = {
    monthActualLWDC = [12,54,65,74,23,47,75,23,57,65,45,33]
}
```

Then you can use the value as an index into the object:

```
function changeTheVariable() {
    var chartdata = mYData[document.getElementById("btn2").value];
    // code here that uses chartdata to display the chart
}
```